# Using filter function on dataframe in formula of walk function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to print a data sample of the `mpg` dataframe for each of the `drv` types in `mpg` ('f','r','4'). I tried to do it the following way using the `walk` function:

`walk(unique(mpg$drv),~print(mpg %>% filter(drv == .) %>% head()))`

But the result for each of the drive types using this method is an empty tibble.

The following method works perfectly but I wanted to understand what's wrong with the previous one.

`walk(drives,~print(mpg[mpg$drv == .,] %>% head()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using pipes `.` refers to an object coming from LHS (left hand side) of the pipe. In this case it is dataframe `mpg` what you need is the current value of `drv` to `filter`. You can use `.x` to refer it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

walk(unique(mpg$drv),~print(mpg %>% filter(drv == .x) %>% head()))
```

It works for the second case because you are not using pipes there before using `.`.